# How do I install the Ada compiler?

Tags: software-installation

Is there a free Ada compiler available for Linux, in particular Ubuntu 12.04? If so, where can I find it, how do I install it and how do I run it?

Comment: What is ADA? This seems to be to general to find a specific answer.

Comment: I guess you are talking about https://www.adacore.com/adaanswers/about/ada, aren't you?

Comment: From GCC source it is really hard: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/gcc-ada.html You need precompiled binaries, and installing `sudo apt-get install gnat` does not help, maybe not up to date enough?

Answer (score 12):

Ubuntu comes with the Ada compiler GNAT (package `gnat`) as part of the GNU Compiler Collection and the GNAT Programming Studio (package `gnat-gps`), an IDE for GNAT.

See [AdaCore documentation page](http://libre.adacore.com/developers/documentation) for documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Looking in the terminal's history on a Ubuntu 10.04 VM here, I have `sudo apt-get install gnat-4.4` and it appears to have worked at the first time. Perhaps the GNAT version is not even needed there.